# would rather hadn't stayed / not have stayed

Tags: past-perfect, perfect-infinitive

I think there is difference between these two sentences, but can't quite feel it. Could anyone tell me if there is indeed some distinction.

1) He would rather hadn't stayed for dinner

2) He would rather not have stayed for dinner

thank you in advance!

Comment: The second is correct. The first omits to say **who** didn't stay.

Comment: Actually, neither is correct.  The second would only be correct if you were to insert the word "to" before "have."  In so doing, "to have stayed for dinner" becomes a thing, a thing he didn't prefer.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman in the present tense, would *you* say "He would rather not to stay for dinner"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a slight tweak to the first sentence, the only possible difference in interpretation becomes the referent of the person who stayed for dinner in the first sentence.

---

> 1. He would rather **he** hadn't stayed for dinner.

The sentence is ungrammatical without the addition of the second pronoun.

But it's possible, although unlikely barring further context, to interpret the second *he* as referring to somebody other than the first *he*.

> John didn't like celebrities, and he didn't like having to deal with them staying for dinner. He certainly never got along with Elvis when he was alive. *He would have rather he hadn't stayed for dinner* that one night years ago.

Here, in the phrase in italics, the first *he* is referring to John, while the second *he* is referring to Elvis.  It can be ambiguous, but the context of the surrounding passage makes the meaning clear.

---

> 2. He would rather not have stayed for dinner.

In this sentence, *he* is only used once, and the person referred to as having stayed for dinner is the narrator of the sentence. In short, there can be no ambiguity.

---

But assuming that the first and second *he* in the first sentence refer to the same person, then both sentences mean the same thing, and the only difference is one of style.